# Get all the different types of patterns of occurences of elements in a dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

I have this dataset that comprises only a single column. What I need to find out is all the patterns in which data is arranged in that particular column.

I tried doing something using the `pd.duplicated()` function. But it's not giving the results properly.

For ex:

dataset:

```
Column A
[1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4]
```

The required result should be `[1,2,3]` , `[1,2,3,4]` , [1,2], [3,1,2] etc

The solution may be attained irrespective of any packages in Python.

Comment: how do you define a "pattern"? For example, why are your patterns not `[1,2]`, `[3,1,2]` and `[3,4]`

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I need all the patterns including the ones you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

A good old fashioned double loop is not elegant, but will work:

I add as tuples so that I can use `set(...)` to remove duplicates.

```
ls = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4]

set([tuple(ls[i:j+1]) for i in range(len(ls)) for j in range(i, len(ls))])
```

Output

```
{(1,),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 3, 1),
 (1, 2, 3, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1),
 (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1),
 (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 1),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4),
 (2,),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 3, 1),
 (2, 3, 1, 2),
 (2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
 (2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4),
 (2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1),
 (2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2),
 (2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3),
 (2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1),
 (2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2),
 (2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
 (2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4),
 (2, 3, 4),
 (2, 3, 4, 1),
 (2, 3, 4, 1, 2),
 (2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3),
 (2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1),
 (2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2),
 (2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
 (2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4),
 (3,),
 (3, 1),
 (3, 1, 2),
 (3, 1, 2, 3),
 (3, 1, 2, 3, 4),
 (3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1),
 (3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2),
 (3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3),
 (3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1),
 (3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2),
 (3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
 (3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4),
 (3, 4),
 (3, 4, 1),
 (3, 4, 1, 2),
 (3, 4, 1, 2, 3),
 (3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1),
 (3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2),
 (3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
 (3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4),
 (4,),
 (4, 1),
 (4, 1, 2),
 (4, 1, 2, 3),
 (4, 1, 2, 3, 1),
 (4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2),
 (4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
 (4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4)}
```